# Is it possible to use a back reference to specify the number of replications in a regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

Is it possible to use a back reference to specify the number of replications in a regular expression?

foo= 'ADCKAL+2AG.+2AG.+2AG.+2AGGG+.G+3AGGa.'

The substrings that start with '+[0-9]' followed by '[A-z]{**n**}.' need to be replaced with simply '+' where the variable **n** is the digit from earlier in the substring.  Can that **n** be back referenced?  For example (doesn't work) '+([0-9])[A-z]{/1}.' is the pattern I want replaced with "+"  (that last dot can be any character and represents a quality score) so that foo should come out to ADCKAL+++G.G+.

```
 import re
 foo = 'ADCKAL+2AG.+2AG.+2AG.+2AGGG+.+G+3AGGa.'
 indelpatt = re.compile('\+([0-9])')
 while indelpatt.search(foo):
     indelsize=int(indelpatt.search(foo).group(1))
     new_regex = '\+%s[ACGTNacgtn]{%s}.' % (indelsize,indelsize)
     newpatt=re.compile(new_regex)
     foo = newpatt.sub("+", foo)
```

I'm probably missing an easier way to parse the string.

Comment: Should the `2AGGG^` be `4AGGG^`?

Comment: Sincerely sorry about that, I changed the input string to get rid of some other things that needed to parsed out from my example.  My original post contained "foo = 'ADCKAL+2AG.+2AG.+2AG.+2AGGG^+.+G+3AGGa4.'" which would get parsed down to 'ADCKAL++++G^+.+G+4.', but the while loop still returned as true because of the new +4 at the end!

Comment: FYI, if `[A-z]` isn't a typo, it's almost certainly an error.  If you want to match any uppercase or lowercase ASCII letter, `[A-Za-z]` is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot use back-references as quantifiers. A workaround is to construct a regular expression that can handle each of the cases in an alternation.

```
import re

foo = 'ADCKAL+2AG.+2AG.+2AG.+2AGGG^+.+G+3AGGa4.'
pattern = '|'.join('\+%s[ACGTNacgtn]{%s}.' % (i, i) for i in range(1, 10))
regex = re.compile(pattern)
foo = regex.sub("+", foo)
print foo
```

Result:

```
ADCKAL++++G^+.+G+4.
```

Note also that your code contains an error that causes it to enter an infinite loop on the input you gave.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution works great.  I'll change my example code, tried to edit out some additional information.  Sorry about that.